# Weird compiler error in generic class using the Linq ExceptBy function

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the following code (distilled from my production code), which should compile but does not:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public abstract class LocalizableEntity<TLocalizedEntity> where TLocalizedEntity : class, ILocalizedData, new()
        {
            public abstract string Id { get; set; }  // Primary key
            public abstract List<TLocalizedEntity> LocalizedData { get; set; }
        }

        public interface ILocalizedData
        {
            string CultureName { get; set; }
        }

        public void MergeData<TEntity, TLocalizedEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> newItems)
            where TEntity : LocalizableEntity<TLocalizedEntity>
            where TLocalizedEntity : class, ILocalizedData, new()
        {
            // Get the existing items
            var existingItems = new List<TEntity>();

            // Get the deleted items
            var deletedItems = existingItems
                .ExceptBy(newItems, x => x.Id, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the Linq `ExceptBy` function chokes on the generic input types. As written, that line gives me a compiler error that highlights `ExceptBy` and says it can't infer the generic type parameters from the usage.

> The type arguments for method `'Enumerable.ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TKey>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>?)'` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

If I modify the offending statement to specify the generic Types I get a different error:

```
var deletedItems = existingItems
    .ExceptBy<TEntity, string>(newItems, x => x.Id, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Now the compiler highlights the `existingItems` variable and complains:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'ExceptBy' and the best extension method overload `'Queryable.ExceptBy<TEntity, string>(IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<string>, Expression<Func<TEntity, string>>, IEqualityComparer<string>?)'` requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

Ok, I don't know what the "receiver" is in this error message, but it seems to be complaining about `existingItems` not implementing `IQueryable`, so I add `.AsQueryable` like this:

```
var deletedItems = existingItems
    .AsQueryable()
    .ExceptBy<TEntity, string>(newItems, x => x.Id, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

And now it thinks that `newItems` is an `IEnumerable<string>` (*not* an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`) and it complains that it can't convert from `IEnumerable<TEntity>` to `IEnumerable<string>`

I give up. Am I doing something horribly wrong, or is the compiler just confused by the complex generic types?

Comment: @Charlieface , Oh! Man, I wish the good folks at Microsoft would add just a teensy little example to the docs! Please copy-and-paste your comment as an "answer" and I'll accept it as the correct answer. Thanks! (Of course, it would help if I had actually *read* the documentation carefully, which, now that I look at it, tells me that it wants an `IEnumerable<TKey>` containing keys. Duh.)

Comment: ExceptBy on an empty list returns an empty list; this code is a no-op?

Comment: Only if you can get it to compile ;) The point of the question is about the syntax, not the operation.

Comment: Oh.. OK.. Just so you know; once it compiles, it'll need changing before it will do anything "useful"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ExceptBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.exceptby?view=net-6.0) expects the second parameter (first after `this` source enumerable) to be a list of keys, not of source objects.

So you need the following

```cs
var deletedItems = existingItems
    .ExceptBy(newItems.Select(x => x.Id), x => x.Id, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhOMKV)

You can write an extension function that will do the same

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptByKey<TSource, TKey> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer = null)
  => first.ExceptBy(second.Select(keySelector), keySelector, comparer);
```